# Where would I find Step or Pedometer Data?

Tags: data-request, medical

I am a student at the University of Utah.  I am trying to gather the raw data on 30 or more individuals, preferably 35 - 55 females.  My goal is to have 3 to 6 months worth of raw data.  I have been search everywhere I can think of and can't seem to find a resource to buy the raw data.  Does anyone have ideas on where I can find this type of information?

Comment: Exactly what are you after? Total steps per day? Individual-level covariates (age, weight, home location)? Distance walked? Seems pretty unlikely its out there...

Comment: As @Emre mentioned as an answer, I would suggest targeting folks in person and via the net who have connected devices such as Fitbits/etc (most of which have Open APIs). You can also look into patientslikeme.com which has some researcher resources but I have a feeling they are for larger projects.

Comment: "I am trying to gather the raw data on [...] 35 - 55 females"... things really that bad in Utah? ;)

Comment: I've heard that there are online communities where people post their daily data dumps from 'personal activity monitors' (fitbit and the like).  I would hope that the site would have privacy laws to keep them from just handing the data over to you ... but if they had a way for the individual users to dump the data you wanted, then you might be able to use the community forums to solict people to give your their data for your research.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will look into these.  Sorry for the late responce.  I wasn't notified that anyone responded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are human activity datasets available for research. Some of the better known ones are:

Fordham University, NY
WISDM dataset (walking, jogging, standing, sitting, etc) - no gender/age

*The WISDM (Wireless Sensor Data Mining) Lab is concerned with collecting the sensor data from smart phones and other modern mobile devices (e.g., tablet computers, music players, etc.) and mining this sensor data for useful knowledge. Currently our efforts are mainly focused on the acclerometer and GPS sensor data from these devices, but in the future we will mine the audio sensors (microphones), image sensors (cameras), light sensors, proximity sensors, temperature sensors, pressure sensors, direction sensors (compasses) and various other sensors that reside on these devices.*

http://www.cis.fordham.edu/wisdm/dataset.php

University of Michigan
Collective Activity Dataset

*This page describe a Collective Activity Dataset. This dataset contains 5 different collective activities : crossing, walking, waiting, talking, and queueing and 44 short video sequences some of which were recorded by consumer hand-held digital camera with varying view point.*

http://wwweb.eecs.umich.edu/vision/activity-dataset.html

Here's something else that is fairly new. It is a FitBit activity dataset and analysis. Though I think it is collected from one individual:

https://rpubs.com/dmaurath/24643